# Update custom user password using UpdateWithInlinesView from django-extra-views app

Tags: django, django-forms, django-class-based-views, django-users

I have a model 'Admin' related to a (custom) user within a one to one field. To update all the fields I'm using [django-extra-views app](https://django-extra-views.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that basically use Django formset. It works well but for updating the password.

Models

```
class Users(AbstractUser):
    # common fields for all the users

class Admins(models.Model):
    # Custom fields for the admins
```

Forms:

```
class AdminProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, label='New Password')
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, label='Confirm Password')
```

Views:

```
class AdminInline(InlineFormSet):
    model = Admins
    fields = ['admins_fiels_here']

class AdminProfile(BaseContext, UpdateWithInlinesView):

    ....

    inlines = [AdminInline]
    form_class = AdminProfileForm

    def get_object(self):
        return Users.objects.get(pk=self.request.user.id)

    def forms_valid(self, formset, inlines):
        password1 = formset.cleaned_data['password1']
        password2 = formset.cleaned_data['password2']

        if password2 and password1:
            if password1 != password2:
                # raise a ValidationError message

            user = self.request.user        # at this point password is 'old_passord'
            user.set_password(password1)    # now is 'password1'
            user.save()                     # 'password1' is correctly saved in db

        return super(AdminProfile, self).forms_valid(formset, inlines)
```

As I describe above, the new password is saved but when `super(AdminProfile, self).forms_valid(formset, inlines)` ends its works the password results to be the old one.

Comment: What if you just redirect instead of calling super?